# Docker service is accessible from EC2 Instance (localhost) but not remotely

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, api, amazon-ec2, connection

I have a docker container running a .NET WebAPI. I have configured the container to running using the network mode "host". The reason for this is that I have a MySQL Database running on the same EC2 Instance, but not containerized:

```
services:
  api:
    image: <<>>
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
```

I am able to access the service with wget:

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

However I am unable to access the same when attempting to connect using my EC2 Instance public endpoint. I have made sure that the EC2 Instance security group is allowing HTTP/HTTPS traffic:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your service is running on `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`. `127.0.0.1` is loopback ip address. You can not access `127.0.0.1` from external. EC2 instances has more than one ip addresses.

For more details check [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding an iptables rule to allow traffic on port 80. I've never had to do this but there you go.